# How can I limit the number of rows in an Oracle query

Tags: oracle, limit

I have PHP + Oracle query like this :

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT P.FORM_NO, P.MODEL_NO, P.PRODUCTION_STATUS, P.REMARKS, P.DATE_ADDED, P.TIME, P.QTY_PLAN, M.MODEL_NO, M.MODEL_NAME
                    FROM SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P, SEIAPPS_MODEL M
                    WHERE P.MODEL_NO = M.MODEL_NO ORDER BY P.DATE_ADDED DESC, P.TIME LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

When I tried to search the problem, everyone said the problem is in LIMIT cant used in oracle.
How can I use LIMIT in ORACLE ?

Please advice.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A query for `PHP use LIMIT oracle` should give you everything you need.

Comment: Use `ROWNUM`, such as `WHERE ROWNUM < 50`

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'd even leave *PHP* out of that search. *"oracle limit"* gets you the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition with where clause such as 
"AND rownum <= 500"